# Google Data Flow Template

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Hi I have configured google cloud tools for eclipse and am facing this issue after cloning Dataflow templates from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates, I have added all these dependencies auto-service-1.0-rc1.jar, guava-16.0.1.jar, jsr-305-2.0.3.jar,auto-value-1.0-rc1.jar but could not resolve the issue :AutoValue_DynamicJdbcIO_DynamicRead.Builder could not be resolved to a type

Comment: I am facing the same. Did you fix the issue ?